# How to select and use the last digits if number is above 1000

Tags: javascript

I have a very simple code and function. *My problem is*: I want to select the last digit of a given number, which I did but when I want to use it, it simply won't work.

My job in this function is to make numbers more readable, so for example: 
if number is **1**, output must be **1st**; if number is **3**, output must be **3rd**; if number is **402** output must be **402nd**.

```
function humanizeChar (number) {  
var lastOne = number.toString().split('').pop();
  if (lastOne === 1) {
    return number + 'st';
  } else if (lastOne === 2) {
    return number + 'nd';
  } else if (lastOne === 3) {
    return number + 'rd';
  } else {
    return number + 'th';
  } 
}
console.log(humanizeChar(1131)); // my output is 1131th
```

Comment: `lastOne` is a string. `'1' === 1` is `false`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks, i thought i changed that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a string (`lastOne`) to a number with [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity_strict_equality_()) `===`, that compares the value and the type. You can use [simple equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Equality_()) `==` or change the numbers to strings:

```js
function humanizeChar (number) {  
  var lastOne = number.toString().split('').pop();
  console.log(lastOne);
  if (lastOne === '1') {
    return number + 'st';
  } else if (lastOne === '2') {
    return number + 'nd';
  } else if (lastOne === '3') {
    return number + 'rd';
  } else {
    return number + 'th';
  } 
}
console.log(humanizeChar(1131)); // my output is 1131th
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have accepted your answer because of your quick response

Answer (score 1):

Try this, seem you compare the output string with the number:

```
function humanizeChar (number) {  
var lastOne = number.toString().split('').pop();
  if (lastOne === "1") {
    return number + 'st';
  } else if (lastOne === "2") {
    return number + 'nd';
  } else if (lastOne === "3") {
    return number + 'rd';
  } else {
    return number + 'th';
  } 
}
console.log(humanizeChar(1131)); // my output is 1131th
```

Comment: Your answer will be more useful to others if you explain what the problem is and how your solutions solves it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is, that you are comparing strings with numbers, using the `===` operator. As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/2169988) very good answer on SO:

> The identity (===) operator behaves identically to the equality (==)
>   operator except no type conversion is done, and the types must be the
>   same to be considered equal.

So you could either convert your `lastOne` manually to a number (e.g. using `parseInt(lastOne)`) or use the `==` operator instead. Or you could compare `lastOne` to string literals (`'1'`,`'2'`,...) instead.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript Comparison Operators
Operator    Description
==           equal to
===          equal value and equal type

in your case the correct operator is '=='

Answer (score 1):

You need to make some changes in your code like below:-

```
function humanizeChar (number) {
number = 7882;          //just give some number for checking
var lastOne = number.toString().split('').pop();
//console.log(lastOne);
  if (lastOne == 1) {
    return number + 'st';
  } else if (lastOne == 2) {
    return number + 'nd';
  } else if (lastOne == 3) {
    return number + 'rd';
  } else {
    return number + 'th';
  } 
}
console.log(humanizeChar());
```

Answer (score 1):

We also need to account the 2nd from last digit.  For example, 101 should be one hundred and first instead of one hundred and oneth.

```js
//Improving from Ori Drori's answer
function humanizeChar (number) {
    var numStrs = number.toString().split('');
    var lastOne = numStrs.pop();
    var isSeondFromLastGreaterThanZero = (numStrs.length > 0 && numStrs.pop() !== '0');
    var suffix = "th";

    if (!isSeondFromLastGreaterThanZero) {
        if (lastOne === '1') {
            suffix = 'st';
        } else if (lastOne === '2') {
            suffix = 'nd';
        } else if (lastOne === '3') {
            suffix = 'rd';
        }
    }

    return number.toString() + suffix;

}
console.log(humanizeChar(1131)); // my output is 1131th
console.log(humanizeChar(1101)); // 1101st
console.log(humanizeChar(2)); // 2nd
```